# How can we use alias in a case statement with multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to toggle between 2 columns of a table using a case statement. 
Here is my code:

```
CASE WHEN :currency_flag ='Y' THEN tr.TRXN_RPTNG_AM ELSE 0 END as TRXN_RPTNG_AM
CASE WHEN :currency_flag ='N' THEN tr.TRXN_BASE_AM ELSE 0 END  as  TRXN_BASE_AM
```

Here I need to consider trxn_rptng_am if the currency flag is Y and trxn_base_am if currency flag is N.

Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: That's case expressions, not case statements. (A case expression has a return value. A case statement is conditional execution of code, e.g. in a stored procedure.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the two expressions into one:

```
CASE :currency_flag
    WHEN 'Y' THEN tr.TRXN_RPTNG_AM
    WHEN 'N' THEN tr.TRXN_BASE_AM
    ELSE 0
END AS TRXN_SWITCHED
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. but here my requirement is to either get trxn_rptng_am or trxn_base_am. these are columns from a table so if the currency flag is Y i need to pick  trxn_rptng_am from the table and if it is N then i need to pick trxn_base_am.

Comment: He want the column name to change according to `currency_flag`

Comment: @user2523599 When you put this `CASE` expression into a `SELECT` you would get a column called `TRXN_SWITCHED`. The value of that column is going to be either `tr.TRXN_RPTNG_AM` or `tr.TRXN_BASE_AM`, depending on the value of the `:currency_flag` switch. The name of the column is going to be the same, though.

Comment: @user2523599... But i need to have the same column name as from the table as this column name will be used by other data sets to for join conditions n all. So is it possible to achieve it using case, if not, can you suggest some other approach

Comment: @user2523599 You cannot rename or hide a column in the `SELECT`. You can put `NULL` instead of zero so that at most one of the two columns would have any value, but the number of columns and their names are going to stay the same.

Comment: @user2523599: Your comments to this answer suggest that you are not really looking for how to toggle between the two case expressions, but something else that has to do with a conditional join. I suggest you accept this answer and then ask the question that you really want to ask. And with such questions: Show sample data and results, so we get an idea what you want to achieve.